# Как изменить часть ASP.NET проекта не перекомпилировав весь?

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp.net, soap, asp

Есть большой проект - исходников нет, и в нём есть один отчет, который состоит из следующего:

Report.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"%>
 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Список дебиторов/кредиторов</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Wed, 26 Feb 1999 08:21:57 GMT">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content ="no-cache"> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ru">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
...
 
function WebService()
        {
            this.HttpMethod = "POST";
            this.Namespace = "http://integro.ru/estate/";
            //this.Url = "<%=requestUrl %>/EstateSaleStatmentRevise.asmx";
            this.Url = "TableCreaterService.asmx";
        }
 
...
```

TableCreaterService.asmx:

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="TableCreaterService.asmx.cs" Class="Integro.InMeta.Estate.Forms.EstateSale.TurnoverBalanceSheet.TableCreaterService" %>
```

TableCreaterService.asmx.cs:

```
using System.Web.Services;
using Integro.InMeta.Estate.Forms.EstateRent;
using Integro.InMeta.Runtime;
using WebService = Integro.InMeta.Web.WebService;
 
namespace Integro.InMeta.Estate.Forms.EstateSale.TurnoverBalanceSheet
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://integro.ru/estate/")]
    public class TableCreaterService : WebService
    { 
        private const string EstateSaleProcessClassName = "Estate/SaleProcess";
        private const string LoadPlan = @"
                                <Estate_SaleContract query-all-properties='true'/>
                                <Estate_SaleProcessPurchaser>
                                    <Subject>
                                        <query-view name='SubjectName'/>
                                    </Subject>
                                </Estate_SaleProcessPurchaser>
                                <Estate_SaleCalculationONF query-all-properties='true'>
                                    <Estate_RentPaymentStep query-all-properties='true'/>
                                </Estate_SaleCalculationONF>
                                <Estate_PersonalAccountProcessLink>
                                    <PersonalAccount>
                                        <Estate_RentPayment query-all-properties='true'/>
                                        <Estate_RentWriteOff query-all-properties='true'/>
                                    </PersonalAccount>
                                </Estate_PersonalAccountProcessLink>";
 
        private int RowNo;
        private StringBuilder FErrorList;
 
...
 
   }
}
```

**Как его можно изменить?**

Я пытался так: создал новую библиотеку на основании "TableCreaterService.asmx.cs" -"TableCreaterServiceNew.dll":

```
 using System.Web.Services;
    using Integro.InMeta.Estate.Forms.EstateRent;
    using Integro.InMeta.Runtime;
    using WebService = Integro.InMeta.Web.WebService;
    using Integro.InMeta.Estate.Forms.EstateSale;
     
    namespace TableCreaterServiceNew
    {
        [WebService(Namespace = "http://integro.ru/estate/")]
        public class TableCreaterServiceNew : WebService
        {   
            private const string EstateSaleProcessClassName = "Estate/SaleProcess";
            private const string LoadPlan = @"
                                    <Estate_SaleContract query-all-properties='true'/>
                                    <Estate_SaleProcessPurchaser>
                                        <Subject>
                                            <query-view name='SubjectName'/>
                                        </Subject>
                                    </Estate_SaleProcessPurchaser>
                                    <Estate_SaleCalculationONF query-all-properties='true'>
                                        <Estate_RentPaymentStep query-all-properties='true'/>
                                    </Estate_SaleCalculationONF>
                                    <Estate_PersonalAccountProcessLink>
                                        <PersonalAccount>
                                            <Estate_RentPayment query-all-properties='true'/>
                                            <Estate_RentWriteOff query-all-properties='true'/>
                                        </PersonalAccount>
                                    </Estate_PersonalAccountProcessLink>";
     
            private int RowNo;
            private StringBuilder FErrorList;
     
    ...
//Something to change
       }
    }
```

А в файле TableCreaterService.asmx прописал/заменил:

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#"  Class="TableCreaterServiceNew.TableCreaterServiceNew" %>
```

Но это почему-то не сработало?
В самом коде проблем нет - новая библиотека собирается, код там почти тот же самый, что и в файле "TableCreaterService.asmx.cs" проекта с небольшими корректировками. Библиотеку кидаю в BIN, но она не срабатывает - работает старый код

Comment: А проект слишком долго компилируется?

Comment: Это программа написанная лет 12 назад сторонней компанией, а исходников нет  (

Comment: были бы исходники было бы проще

Comment: Там где ваши куски  CodeBehind - обязателен. Там где чужие куски -  CodeBehind должен отсутствовать (иначе надо подставить исходник). По коду не понятно в чём именно проблема. Ошибок вы не показали. А вообще так можно, что б часть кода в cs-как, а часть в dll. У меня так проэкт работает.

Comment: В самом коде проблем нет - новая библиотека собирается, код там почти тот же самый, что и в файле "TableCreaterService.asmx.cs" проекта с небольшими корректировками. Библиотеку кидаю в BIN, но она не срабатывает - работает старый код

Comment: Попробовал оставить параметр CodeBehind в TableCreaterService.asmx - результат тот же